# How to randomly select a row based on given probabilities in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['a',0,0.2],['b',0,0.3],
...                    ['c',0,0.5],
...                    ['a',1,0.4],['b',1,0.3],['c',1,0.3],
...                    ['a',2,0.5],['b',2,0.5]]
...                    ,columns=['place','ID','prob'])
>>> df
place   ID  prob
0   a   0   0.20
1   b   0   0.30
2   c   0   0.50
3   a   1   0.40
4   b   1   0.30
5   c   1   0.30
6   a   2   0.50
7   b   2   0.50
```

I want to use the prob column as a probability mass distribution to randomly pick one of the rows within each ID. That is, I only want to select one row within each 'ID'. The output would look like this:

```
place   ID  prob    choice
0   a   0   0.20    1
1   b   0   0.30    0
2   c   0   0.50    0
3   a   1   0.40    0
4   b   1   0.30    1
5   c   1   0.30    0
6   a   2   0.50    1
7   b   2   0.50    0
```

The real dataframe will have millions of rows, so the more efficient the better. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use your `prob` as weights in `DataFrame.sample`. Only thing we have to do is to use this in a `GroupBy`, since we want to do this for each group in `place`:

```
sample = df.groupby("ID").apply(lambda x: x.sample(weights=x["prob"]))
choices = sample.reset_index(drop=True, level=0).index
df["choice"] = df.index.isin(choices).astype(int)

  place  ID  prob  choice
0     a   0   0.2       0
1     b   0   0.3       1
2     c   0   0.5       0
3     a   1   0.4       1
4     b   1   0.3       0
5     c   1   0.3       0
6     a   2   0.5       0
7     b   2   0.5       1
```

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I needed.. except for I'll be grouping by ID, but that's a minor point. Thanks again!